# How do we add a popup window using PyQt?

Tags: pyqt4

Hi I need to create a pop up window when user clicks a button in the MainWindow.
So I created a DialogWindow and linked it with MainWindow with below line of code.
For note I've three modules 1. MainWindow_Ui.py 2. About_Ui.py 3. UiShow.py

Below line of code is included in MainWindow_Ui.py and the module imports < from About_Ui import * >, but still I get the error "global name 'dialog' is not defined". Please suggest. Thanks!

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.menuAbout, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), dialog.setupUi(aboutDialog))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in your dialog **init**

```
QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
self.ui = Ui_your_dialog_window()
self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

then connect your *self.menuAbout* to a slot that creates that dialog
Example:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.menuAbout, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), self.createDialog)
```

**slot:**

```
def createDialog(self):
    myDialog= your_class_dialog()
    myDialog.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks Nerkyator. That was a total mess in my code. I changed a lot in it. Your answer helped me out. Thanks!